# How to load static script files in Vue CLI 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an existing project made with Vue CLI 2, and I'm working on moving this to Vue CLI 3, but I get the following **error**:

```
1: "vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: _ is not defined"
```

```
2: "vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
```

I think this is due to `index.html`. In Vue CLI 2, `index.html` was in the project root, but Vue CLI 3 has it in the `public` folder. And projects created with Vue CLI 2 load Jquery, Underscore, Bootstrap, etc. in `index.html`.

How can I solve these problems in Vue CLI 3 and get the same results as an existing project?

**Vue CLI 2 `index.html`**:

```html
...
<!--Jquery -->
<script src="/blk/static/assets/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/blk/static/assets/lib/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!--Bootstrap-->
<script src="/blk/static/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/blk/static/assets/bootstrap/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/moment-2.4.0.js"></script> -->
<script src="/blk/static/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<script src="/blk/static/assets/lib/classie.js"></script>
<script src="/blk/static/assets/lib/custom.js"></script>
<!--underscore -->
<script src="/blk/static/assets/lib/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
...
```

**The part of code that is causing the problem**:

```js
const example = _.indexOf(path,'example'); // underscore not defined
...
$('#openDate').datetimepicker({ // "$" not defined
    locale: 'us',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
});
```

Comment: You can try switching to NPM versions of these libraries and then import them in your `main.js` - but I strongly advice you to get rid of all these legacies. For example, jQuery can be imported like `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

Comment: You most likely mean Vue CLI 2 and Vue CLI 3, as Vue 3 is not yet available.

Comment: @IVO GELOV 
I tried it but I get the error "[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook:" TypeError: $ (...). Datetimepicker is not a function ".

Comment: @tony19 it's correct.

Comment: You will suffer much less pain if you try to replace these jQuery plugins (and jQuery itself) with Vue-compatible alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Let's integrate jQuery with Vue.js

#### 1. install jQuery

```
$ npm install jquery --save
```

#### 2. check your package.json

Here is how it looks like. it will be added jquery library with specific version.

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "^3.4.1"
}
```

#### 3. define jQuery in your vue component.

```
<template>
 <!-- HTML markup in here -->
</template>
<script>
window.$ = window.jQuery = window.jquery = require('jquery')

export default {
  name: 'component name'
}
</script>
```